# Is there a way to make my python file unreadable? So nobody could check the code?

Tags: python

I'm making some code that I need to be secure, so is there a way I can make the file unreadable and only "runnable"?

Thank you and sorry if the question is noobish, all help would be appreciated :)

(Python 3, BTW)

Comment: It's advisable to frame your question properly while writing in this forum. Also, when possible, share what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for the help, what i did was save the file as a pyo... yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want obfuscate your code, [Pyminifier](https://github.com/liftoff/pyminifier) is the library which you are searching for. It will obfuscate your code completely and even you could do change the code in unicode by using --nonlatin option.